# Installing Bitlocker on Windows 7 with TPM version 2.0 chip

Tags: windows-7, windows, bitlocker, tpm

We are trying to turn on bitlocker with Windows 7 where the laptop is new and has a TPM version 2.0 NOT 1.4 chip in it.  We ***cannot*** upgrade to Windows 10 due to company policy rules and we have tried to install the Hotfix: [Update to add support for TPM 2.0 in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2920188) which does not seem to work.  When running TPM.msc It still complains that the laptop doesnt contain a TPM 1.4 chip.

How does one go about enabling this even if it is using the command line or working around this?

Can anyone help with a way to be able to do this in Windows 7?

***EDIT***: Due to company policy we need to get this working with the TPM Chip

Comment: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-enable-bitlocker-without-tpm-chip-windows-7-windows-8?page=0%2C1 If you want to get around it try this.

Comment: Thanks @NetworkKingPin but I forgot to add that corporate policy requires us TPM chip

Comment: That is completely understandable we have them in our PCs Not sure which ones in fact i will check.

Comment: Have you Tried Uninstalling it and then Scanning for hardware changes then trying to use it again?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I did but to be honest I dont remember exactly what the solution was in the end.  I think we had to upgrade to windows 10.  But I am not sure now.

Answer (score -1):

You can get around this by going to the TPM device in device manager and selecting Update driver.  Tell it to Look for existing drivers on your computer and select show compatible drivers.  You should see TPM 2.1 listed.  Select that and you should be able enable BitLocker after that as desired.